# Android running a class only once on an Activity

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have written a class and only want it to run once within that activity.

So when the activity is resumed this class will no longer have any effect and another class will take effect.

So lets say on first launch of the ACTIVITY, not application, it will carry out the class, and on every other launch it will do something else. If the app is closed and reentered, it will remember that the class has already run and wont do it.

I hope this all makes sense!

Heres the class i want to run only once:

```
//Should only happen on first launch of activity.
    public void AgeCalculation() {

            if (male == true && age >= 18) {
                newweight = (weight * 0.8);
            }
            weightresultText.setText(Double.toString(newweight));
            //Saves Weight to sharedpreference to use later.
            SaveWeight();
        }
```

Heres the class that will run every other time:

```
    //runs on every other launch of activity

        public void AfterFirstLaunch(){
//The button clicks get the saved value and increments it and saves it again.
            buttonClick1();
            buttonClick2();
            buttonClick3();
            buttonClick4();
            buttonClick5();

            //receive value on other launches and show on field.

            SharedPreferences shoulderPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ShoulderWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String newweight =  shoulderPreference.getString("storednewweight", "");
            weightresultText.setText(newweight);
        }
```

Comment: Good luck to you. It shouldn't be too difficult. Especially since you seem to already know how to use `SharedPreferences` so just save a flag there and check it

Comment: You should check out the chart on http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html - it provides a nice graphical guide to when each of the different methods on an activity are called.  I think it's just what you need.

Comment: That, or you could look into SharedPreferences, which store data regardless of whether or not you close the app (e.g. high scores)

Comment: Not too sure what to do with flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inherited method called `onCreate()` in an Activity that is called whenever the Activity is created.

In order to check if an Activity was already running, in the `onCreate()` method you can check to see if the passed in parameter `Bundle savedInstanceState` is null.

On the Activity's first run, `savedInstanceState` will be null. Any subsequent "creations" will make `savedInstanceState` NOT null as it was already created.

So, in order to achieve the results you are looking for you would have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // The Activity is brand new
        AgeCalculation();
    }
    else {
        // The Activity has been re-created
        AfterFirstLaunch();
    }

    // ... Other stuff
}
```

By the way, you say you want to run these different "classes" but I assume you mean methods?

EDIT: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you need to fill the shared preference on the first run only?

If that's the case then you just need to check if your shared preference exists like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences shoulderPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ShoulderWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // The second parameter in getString() is the default value which
    // is returned if the prefernece "storednewweight" does not
    // exist (yet)
    String prefValue =  shoulderPreference.getString("storednewweight", "");

    if(prefValue.equals("")) {
        // The preference was not created before
        AgeCalculation();
    }
    else {
        // Preference already created
        AfterFirstLaunch();
    }

    // ... Other stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes meant methods, sorry about that haha, this is good but hasnt helped solve my problem, am starting to think its an unrelated issue.

Comment: I removed the AfterFirstLaunch from my onresume and used your if for oncreate and now it doesnt carry out the AfterFirstLaunch function

Comment: No problem. What's the issue with this solution exactly? So I can understood fully. No, onResume() is a completely separate method and is also called whenever the Activity is started so it wouldn't help you in this case.
The else in my example basically means that the Activity has been created before

Comment: I am starting to think its something to do with storing of values to sharedpreferences which arent working properly. I will let you know if its this or if its that.

Comment: Do you need this behaviour to persist forever? For example, on the first run of the Activity AgeCalculation() is run, then for **EVERY** run after that, including if the device is switched off and back on, that AfterFirstLaunch() is called?

Comment: Haha glad to be of help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [developper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) site for android everything is explained there.

So you would have something like that:

```
protected void onCreate() {
    AgeCalculation();
    super.onCreate(); //since we overridden it we want it to run too.
}

protected void onResume() { //it could be on start depending on what you want
    AfterFirstLaunch();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Its just showing the same initial value from AgeCalculation and not doing the Afterlaunch process.